# break loop if condition is met

Tags: python, while-loop

i want to end the `while True` loop if `num4 == number` but break stops the loop from repeating and not making the `if statement` a part of the `while True` loop makes the code inaccessible.
the code is below:

```
number = 50
count = 0
num4 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
while True:
    if num4 > number:
        print("Too high")
        num4 = int(input("Try again: "))

    elif num4 < number:
        print("Too low")
        num4 = int(input("Try again: "))

    elif num4 == number:
        print("Well done, you took", count, "attempts")
```

Comment: Just add a `break` to that statement

Comment: You say "i want to end the while True loop". OK, fine. Use `break`. Then you say "but break stops the loop from repeating". Yes, it does. That's what you asked for. Now you complain that the loop ends? Could you please clarify this?

Answer (score 0):

Add break statement to break out of a while or for loop. Also looks like you need to increment count variable inside the loop whenever user enters a new number.

```python
while True:
    count += 1
    if ...
        ...
    elif num4 == number:
        print("Well done, you took", count, "attempts")
        break  # <======
```